# Rename field in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: rename, pentaho, kettle

I have a transformation reading 50 fields from a CSV file, and then doing various operations in them with around 100 steps in total. Due to new naming conventions in the project I need to rename all fields.

I could easily rename the fields in the file input step, but this doesn't change the names in any of the places where they are used further downstream. I would have to edit every individual step downstream, with the risk of introducing bugs if I make any mistakes.

Is there no way to automatically change a field name in all steps where it is used?

Comment: you could try just changing the field names in the .ktr file with search/replace in a text editor.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Smart! With some human supervision I think that should work.

Comment: yes, interesting! Please let us now if it worked. Thanks

Comment: don't forget to make backup before changing ktr files in text editor.

Comment: @Seb So far, so good. Works fine. You just need to be on your watch so you don't replace something that just happends to have the same name as the fieldname. Just hitting "Replace all" is not recommended, unless you have very unique field names.

Comment: And yes, @simar, a backup is a very good idea indeed.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek If you post this as an answer, I will accept it since it helped me solve the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks! A backup is  a good point, too.

Comment: you could try replacing with the opening/closing bracket of the xml nodes included in your search and replace strings, e.g. replace ">MyFieldName<" with ">MyNewFieldname<". That would at least take care of string parts somewhere in step configurations or connection information.

Answer (score 1):

The .ktr file containing the transformation data is a simple XML file. You can open it in any text editor and use search/replace to change the field names.